# Привязка отображаемого свойства элемента коллекции к Picker

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin

Есть список `Picker`, к которому я привязал данные:

```xml
<Picker x:Name="pickerName" ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}" />
```

Languages это `List<LanguageModel>`, где LanguageModel:

```cs
public class LanguageModel
{
    public string? translationLanguageCode = null!;
            
    public string code { get; set; } = null!;
    
    public string translatedName { get; set; } = null!;
    
    public bool? nativeLanguage { get; set; }
    
    public bool? learningLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

В моем случае `Languages` состоит из 18 объектов.

Вопрос в том, как сделать так, что бы текст выпадающего списка был привязан к `ranslatedName`, т.е. в выпадающем списке я видел названия языков? Да, я могу сделать список только из `translatedName`, но и `code` мне так же нужен, т.к. когда пользователь выбирает язык, то я запоминаю поле `code`

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще некуда.

```xml
<Picker x:Name="pickerName"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding translatedName}"/>
```

---

Так же привяжите `SelectedItem`, создайте новое свойство, там где у вас `Languages`. В нём и будет нужный `code`.

```xml
<Picker x:Name="pickerName"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding translatedName}"/>
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!